# Почему во Vue для <input type="text"> используют @keyup.enter вместо `onchange` (@change)?

Tags: vue.js, input

Во многих учебных видео по **Vue** используют событие `v-on:keyup` c модификатором `enter` для прослушивания изменения значения в `<input type="text">`. Но ведь в серии инпутов пользователю логично просто переходить к следующему инпуту, то есть в текущем инпуте будет просто потерян фокус. В таком случае срабатывает событие `change` (как и при нажатии *enter*).

Но почему-то повально и настойчиво используется именно `v-on:keyup.enter`, в чем суть такой "формулировки" для отслеживания банального события изменения значения в input, который прекрасно отслеживается с помощью `onchange`?

Comment: Я бы не спрашивал, если бы Великий Илья Климов не использовал это)))

Comment: Событие `change` эмитится при _любой_ потере фокуса, если что... а иногда надо именно по клавише Enter запускать обработчик. Но вообще хз что там в головах YT-гуру творится.

Comment: В том то и дело, и это по-моему правильно, можно переключаться с помощью Tab, можно просто ткнуть в следующий инпут, и событие (если значение изменилось) сработает. А так все ограничивается нажатием enter. А зачем? И в учебниках и в документации это встречается. Откуда-то же это взялось))

Comment: Может они все из одного бложика читают. Почему бы не обратиться к источнику, автору видео? Этот вопрос вообще о телепатии/догадках, а не о программировании (кстати).

Comment: Я спрашиваю имеет ли эта формулировка какое-то значение на практике, я лично не понимаю почему вообще кому-то должно прийти в голову такое. Вот и спрашиваю. Может исторически сложилось, или есть какой-то смысл, который я не вижу по глупости...

Comment: Значение безусловно имеет, и оно изложено в официальной документации Vue. А вот с какой целью некий персонъ использует это, и о чем он думает при этом - нам неведомо. Исторически вроде бы не сложилось... по крайней мере, каноном не является (в оф.доках, и на вьюфоруме ЛинусБорг так не делают == не канон).

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/130403/discussion-between-yar85-and-leonid).